# What is the recommended way of checking running services?

Tags: debian, centos, services, sles

I'm often exposed to various GNU/Linux systems including CentOS, SLES and Debian.

I want to know: what is the recommended method of checking all running services across these systems?

I am aware of `service --status-all` and `chkconfig` but they are not always available.

Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to know: what is the recommended method of checking all running
>   services across these systems?

Since you are aware of `chkconfig`,`service`, and may be `ntsysv`,`rcconf`,

but you can check using below command which almost work in all flavor

```
ls -1 /etc/rc$(runlevel| cut -d" " -f2).d/S*
```

**What is S* ?**

the traditional init style makes symlinks that start with S, or K. those with S means "start", and they are run with the "start" parameter when that runlevel is entered. Those with K means "kill", those services are run with the "stop" parameter when that runlevel is entered

Full details:

```
ls -1 /etc/rc$(runlevel| cut -d" " -f2).d/S* | \
awk -F'[0-9][0-9]' '{print "Startup :-> " $2}'
```

Output:

```
Startup :-> bind9
Startup :-> apt-cacher-ng
Startup :-> slapd
Startup :-> cron
Startup :-> dmesg
Startup :-> inetutils-inetd
Startup :-> ssh
Startup :-> dns-clean
Startup :-> sudo
Startup :-> apache2
Startup :-> grub-common
Startup :-> ondemand
Startup :-> rc.local
```

Comment: Nice answer, although you might want to correct your spelling of chkconfig for future readers.

Comment: @synack Thanks.. I have corrected that.. if this answer satisfy you, So can you mark it as correct.

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 16.04) your command list -> 41, `rcconf --list | grep " on$" | wc -l` -> 56, `service --status-all | grep -F "[ + ]" | wc -l` -> 47, `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled` [-> 73](https://askubuntu.com/a/795245/349837). Why this might be? Just enabled vs running?

Answer (score 1):

A little less elegant but you can always compare what is running `ps aux` against what is listed in `/etc/init.d/` or `/etc/rc.d/`

Answer (score -1):

Try with the svcs.
svcs should list all the services offline online or maintenance mode..

Comment: Any Debian-like equivalent to this?